# I want my image to disappear everytime I dblclick it

Tags: javascript, dom

I have three image tags when I click one of the images in the webpage I don't it want to disappear it but when I dblclick I want it to disappear.

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
console.log(img)

let c = Array.from(img);
console.log(c);

c.forEach(function(imgs) {
  imgs.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let d = imgs;
    d.addEventListener("dblclick", function(v) {
      console.log(img)
      // I want this eventlistener to make it disapear
      document.querySelectorAll("image").innerHTML = "";
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Isn't it enough to set `display: none` ?

Comment: `querySelectorAll("image")` is not a valid selector

Comment: The clicked element is passed as part of the event parameters to the handler.  There is no need to use a selector inside the handler at all.

Comment: Why are you setting the double click handler *inside* the click handler?  I don't understand why there's a click handler at all, when the question specifies the image should disappear when it is *double clicked*.  Shouldn't that be the only handler you have?

Answer (score 0):

After I read your post again I have made some changes to my answer!

```js
const imgs=document.querySelectorAll("img");
imgs.forEach(function(img){
  img.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    this.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {

  width: 220px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Click the Image to remove it !
  <br>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" style="width: 100%">
  <br><br>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" style="width: 100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Above answer works too.

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
console.log(img)

let c = Array.from(img);
console.log(c);

c.forEach(function(imgs) {
  imgs.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) {
      imgs.style.display = "none";
    })
})
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" width=150 height=150>
```